# OutOfMemory on repo.save() with Pagable (small page, but many total elements)

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, out-of-memory, postgresql-9.5

**Problem:**

I have an application where I process measurements with usually 60k-6m points on a regular basis since a couple of years now.

Now I have a measurement with ~ 43 millions points. **Trying to change the state of even a single point ends up in a OutOfMemory exception**.

The processing runs through for 3 measurements (containing each ~ 60k points) and breaks down on the 4th, very large measurement: The save() method runs forever until I receive the OOM.

**Stack**

Sprint Boot 1.5.16.RELEASE with Hibernate and Postgres 9.5.

**Simplified Code**

```
// pageSize worked with 300k before but for debugging: 500
Page<Point> page = getNextPage(m, pageSize);
ResultCache result = process(page);

// This is the cause of the OOM, even with a single point!
repo.save(result.getChangedPoints());
// save(one single element) also ends up in the OOM so I cannot execut code afterwards like flush

private Page<Point> getNextPage(Measurement m, int pageSize) {
    return repo.findByMeasurement(m, new PageRequest(0, pageSize));
}

@Repository
public interface PointRepository extends 
JpaRepository<Point, Long> {}
```

**Debugging**

When I debug in my IDE I reach the first `repo.save()` statement but as soon as I execute this statement the memory fills itself up until it reaches ~4 GB and after some minutes I receive an OOME.

**Question**

How can I avoid the OOM and why is the total elements number of the Page of any importance? I thought only the page size influences the amount of data loaded into the memory.

**Profiling**

[image: Memory snapshot]

**Update**

- When I reset the point's state (processed = false) the processing runs through again until measurement 4 and then I see the same behaviour.
- I can update the points manually in the database without a problem.

Comment: Have you considered the usage of profilers, in order to see the data that causes the OOM exception ?
For example, jprofiler is one of the best that I've used. https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html
It is not free, but it has a trial version that you can use to find the memory leak.

Comment: I'll give it a go. I used it a year ago which resulted into the pagination which you can see in the code above. I'm just wondering why everything worked with many entries and after processing some data I end up here where I cannot even persist one changed point :-/

Comment: The profiler didn't really help: The code which is causing the OOM is the com.sun.proxy.$Proxy130.save(Iterable) method and the memory is used up by an ArrayList of Objects created from the hibernate persister I think. What I am wondering: why are a couple of million Objects there when I only try to save one page of e.g. 500 Objects?

Comment: Don't call `save(Collection)`. call `save(element)` instead in a `for` loop.  Then each x records do a `flush` and `clear` on the `EntityManager`. This will save memory and boost your performance. Everything you save is stored in the first level cache (the `EntityManager`) the more you add the large it becomes. It will also effect performance as each time you save something hibernate does a dirty check on everything in the first level cache to see if something needs to be flushed with the DB. Another tip, instead of a `Page` return a `Stream` as that will lazy load records from the DB.

Comment: @M.Deinum The problem with flush() is: I cannot reach it as the save(single element) does not finish and ends up in the OOM. `final ArrayList<Point> elements = new ArrayList<>(result.getChangedPoints());
        for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
            repo.save(elements.get(i)); // executing this once ends up in the OOM and does not finish`

`if (i % 1000 == 0) {
                repo.flush();
                //repo.clear(); this does not exist in the JpaRepository interface by default - see code in updated Question
            }
        }`

Comment: I havent tried streaming but will probably migrate to a stream processing / big data stack instead in near future. The question asked here is however more about why the total number of elements of a small Page can lead to an OOM at all. (I updated the question to clearify this.) Thanks for the suggestion anyway - might be helpful for others